# How to get values to update outside of a class or file

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, automation

So at the moment ive been trying to build a python trading bot trying to think of new ways to make the data i need to more accessible and more useable, but 
struck an issue

So i have this code,

```
import requests

binance = "https://api.binance.com"
ticker_24h = "/api/v1/ticker/24hr"

response = requests.get(binance + ticker_24h + "?symbol=ETHBTC").json()

buy_price = response["bidPrice"]
sell_price = response["askPrice"]
last_price = response["lastPrice"]
```

It works in the core application but if i remove it and try to make it its own class it fails to update, making this update would allow me to do so much more with all of this and it would be a great help to me

I've also tried to make accomaning "get" methods

```
def get_buy_price():
    return buy_price
```

to see if that would make it update in any way

Any help would be appreciated

While inside the core application i get what i expect 
(updated or changing number)

while trying to get the data from any other class i get the value of the coin im looking at, at the time i look at it

Comment: Can you show how you have implemented it in a class?

Comment: It is as posted, i accidently left the "while true" in there

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new class object. So, if this is your new class, with filename bot.py,

```py
import requests

class trading_bot: 
    binance = "https://api.binance.com"
    ticker_24h = "/api/v1/ticker/24hr"


    response = requests.get(binance + ticker_24h + "?symbol=ETHBTC").json()

    buy_price = response["bidPrice"]
    sell_price = response["askPrice"]
    last_price = response["lastPrice"]
```

In whichever other file you want to access this from, do the following:

```py
import .bot as bot
new_bot = bot.trading_bot()
```

Then all you have to do is reference the element you're looking for like so

```py
buy_price = new_bot.buy_price
```

Comment: Helps me with classes, but doesnt solve my issue, im still running into the same issue, numbers not updating out side of its own class